# Rename a template when creating it

Tags: nautilus, template

I added the "Empty file" (empty text document) to the `Templates` folder.
Is possible to rename it automatically when I create it? As when using new folder.
My file manager is `nautilus`.

Comment: I don't think you can unless you're willing to write your own `c` or `python` extension...I'd love to be proven wrong.

Comment: @don_crissti Extension? Of nautilus?

Comment: Yeah... you can extend `nautilus` functionality via [extensions](https://developer.gnome.org/libnautilus-extension/stable/)... There are many of them floating around, if you take the time to search the web you might even find one that does what you want.

Comment: @don_crissti The folder for the extensions (that are scripts) is `~/.gnome/nautilus-scripts/`? source http://g-scripts.sourceforge.net/faq.php

Comment: Those are scripts not extensions... I don't know much about them really, I've never used scripts with nautilus but here is a link that may be helpful: https://fedoramagazine.org/integrating-scripts-nautilus/

Comment: there's also this (I"m not familiar with it either): http://bernaerts.dyndns.org/linux/76-gnome/344-nautilus-new-document-creation-menu

Comment: Those are scripts. One title of the link is "Create the script". The folder is `~/.local/share/nautilus/scripts/`. Nautilus will tell you "Executable files in this folder will appears in the Scripts menu." And you will have the scripts menu but only when selecting a file.